# Scheduled flow in Power Automate didn't recognize Daylight Saving Time

Tags: time, triggers, timezone, schedule, power-automate

I have a scheduled flow in Power Automate that runs every Friday at 10 o'clock. But after the daylight saving time changed last week (+1 hour), it runs at 11 o'clock. I thought that this was supposed to change automatically in the background. Any idea what might the issue be?

Comment: Would you mind including a screenshot of your trigger?

Comment: I just saw that we can set the Time zone in the trigger, thank you so much for mentioning it.

Comment: @SimonaB - did setting that solve the issue? If so, you can either answer your own question or you can close this.   Also, keep in mind that when DST starts or stops depends very much on which time zone you are using. For example, this year DST started in the US on March 13, but in Europe on March 27.

Comment: No, timezone will not help. I guess when you change the timezone first time it seems to be fixed. However, it will miss 1 hour again on next day light saving.